# Java, Memcached - how to pass commands to server?

Tags: java, connection, memcached, nio

So ... I have a bit of software that's supposed to communicate with a memcached server (using no external libraries).

For testing purposes, let's settle on a simple `get hello\r\n` command.

I start memcached with the `-vv` option, this is what the command produces via `telnet`:

```
<15 new auto-negotiating client connection
15: Client using the ascii protocol
<15 get hello
>15 END
```

Now here is what the same command issued from my software produces:

```
<15 new auto-negotiating client connection
```

I'm connecting as following:

```
    private void reconnect(){
        InetSocketAddress remote;
        int nofServers = m.servers.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < R; ++i){
            boolean success = false;
            while(!success) {
                try {
                    SocketChannel oldConnection = connections.get(i);
                    if (oldConnection != null) oldConnection.close();

                    remote = m.servers.get((myServerIndex + i) % nofServers).address();
                    SocketChannel chan = SocketChannel.open(remote);
                    chan.configureBlocking(false);
                    chan.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    connections.set(i, chan);
                    success = true;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After that, the software falls into simple enough a NIO loop:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyRequest curr = null;
        this.canHandleNewRequest = true;
        while (true) {
            if (canHandleNewRequest) {
                curr = myQueue.poll();
            }
            if (canHandleNewRequest && curr != null) {
                canHandleNewRequest = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
                    connections.get(i).keyFor(this.selector).interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                }
            }

            try {
                selector.select();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey k = it.next();
                    it.remove();

                    if (!k.isValid()) continue;
                    if (k.isConnectable()) finishConnection(k);
                    else if (k.isReadable()) this.read(k, curr);
                    else if (k.isWritable()) this.write(k, curr);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                reconnect();
            }

            if(curr != null && /*have sent to all servers I need to*/){
                curr = null;
                this.canHandleNewRequest = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

where

```
    private void write(SelectionKey k, MyRequest currentRequest){
        try {
            SocketChannel chan = (SocketChannel) k.channel();
            ByteBuffer out = currentRequest.getSendBuffer(); //DO NOT FLIP (to resume sending from last sent position)
            assert(chan != null);
            assert(out != null);
            //System.out.println(new String(out.array()));
            chan.write(out); //TODO: make this work!

            if(!out.hasRemaining()) { //do not enable read until whole command has been sent
                currentRequest.partiallySent();
                k.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            }

        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //TODO: create response structure
    }
```

I even tried to substitute the write method for a dummy command provider:

```
else if(k.isWritable()){
    SocketChannel chan = (SocketChannel)k.channel();
    ByteBuffer msg = ByteBuffer.wrap("get hello\r\n".getBytes());
    msg.flip();

    while(msg.hasRemaining()) {
        System.out.println("writing ...");
        chan.write(msg);
    }
    k.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}
```

but this only gets stuck in the "writing" loop (never terminates).

You should think that at least the server should react to that command but it doesn't.

So ... how do I get this working?

The second line from the log providing the command via telnet produces,

```
15: Client using the ascii protocol
```

makes me think there might be something I need to send to the server prior to engaging in actual memcached commands... except I seem to miss it in [the protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt).

Help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This seems to be the issue: flipping a buffer in the `getSendBuffer` method and then returning it is not the same as returning it unflipped and then flipping it in the `write` method.

I find this rather strange. Can this be or is this merely masking a different error?

Answer (score 0):

With NIO you should always check whether all of the buffer has been written, which is not being done doing in the first write block.  Having said that, unless there's a lot of data being written, the whole buffer is usually written in a single call to `write`.  So, it's unlikely to be the root problem here.

In the alternative writing code block the `hasRemaining` condition is negated, it should be:

```
while(msg.hasRemaining()) {
    System.out.println("writing ...");
    chan.write(msg);
}
```

Could you include what's being sent first?  Is the first command terminated with `\r\n`?

Comment: whoops, you're right about that ``hasRemaining()`` typo. Corrected, the while loop never gets executed. For some reason I don't understand yet, that buffer must not be flipped THERE.
On the other hand, the buffer MUST be flipped in the ``write``, even though the ``getSendBuffer`` was supposed to do that when returning it for the first time (idea was to send however much the ``.write()`` command would write and then re-enter the main loop. Guess I can scratch that idea. Thank you.

Comment: All flip does is to swap the buffer's limit and position. Basically every time you write into the buffer, the position is moved forward. Calling flip gets the buffer ready to be written in the back out to the channel. The channel's write method will start from the buffer's position and send bytes up to the buffer's limit. So, you should only call flip once after writing to the buffer, then keep calling channel write until has remaining returns false (I.e. Position == limit). The channel write call will never write more than the limit of the buffer (the last byte put in the buffer before flip).